# Mongo says coordinates out of bounds

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a Spring app thats connected to a mongo database, and am using the following code to get documents from a certain collection that are within a radius of a point on Earth:

```
"query" : {
    "location" : {
        "$geoWithin" : {
            "$centerSphere" : [
                [
                    37.33240731,
                    -122.03046898
                ],
                0.0018924144710663706
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Usually this works (for locations in england), however, for some reason these coordinates (in america) give this error:

```
'{ "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 37.3323 
lat: -122.031", "code" : 2 }
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @toHo Yeah it was just the longitude and latitude were the wrong way around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same problem while using spring data mongodb, the very silly mistake was the exchange of lat and long values.

```
    Query query = new BasicQuery(
            "{ location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [
                                 -122.031, 
                                  37.3323
                    "+ rangeInMiles / 3963.2 +
                    " ] } }, visible : true, status : 'ACTIVE' }"
    );
```

Comment: This is correct! I actually figured that out but forgot to post it. Thanks.